# Largest positive number in register

Tags: math, assembly

In assembly we can obtain negative numbers by substracting the positive one from FFFFh and then increasing it by one, so about half of registers is reserved for negative numbers.

And if we multiply two numbers, and the result is too large for one register, the rest is passed to dx.

So, my question is, what is the largest positive number, that can be stored in the register, because when I'm multiplying different pairs of numbers, neither ax nor dx is the same.

Comment: I was going to say 2^(n-1)-1 but then your last paragraph confused me.

Comment: Well, it would be 2^(n-1)-1 in Two's complement, but i assume it's 16's complement.

Comment: I'm sort of surprised I can't find simple duplicate of this... thinking about adding some medium sized answer... But that last sentence eludes me too, dare you put some examples what you observe?

Comment: @Bolololo321 There is no such thing as 16's complement.

Comment: @fuz Actually there is a [16's complement](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/radix_complement) :)

Comment: @MargaretBloom Dafuq?

Comment: @fuz, Well, there's nothing special with the number two.

Comment: It is not at all clear to me what your question is. Can you perhaps clarify your question? Also, you mention the AX and DX registers...are you sure that you're using a 16's-complement architecture? It sounds like you might be talking about the bog-standard x86, which is a 2's-complement machine, like most of the computers you find today.

Comment: @Ped7g I was trying to fill te register ax by multiplying it by number, which is large enough. Then the remainder would be stored in dx register. But i guess it was just the wrong way of thinking.

Comment: uh.. you made me even more confused now. When you do `mul bx`, then `dx:ax = ax * bx`, where `ax` and `bx` on argument side are two 16 bit values. The `dx:ax` on the result side is meant like single 32 bit number, which has upper 16 bits stored in `dx`, and lower 16b stored in `ax`. For example `ax = 0x1000`, `bx = 0x0010`, `ax*bx = 0x00010000` (overflows 16 bits), which is stored into `dx:ax` pair as: `dx = 0x0001` and `ax = 0x0000`. If you are on 386+, you can extract that into 32b edx like: `shl edx,16` `mov dx,ax` to get `edx = 0x00010000`. So the `ax` contains always the low 16b of result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can interpret **the same register contents** either as signed number, or  as unsigned number. In the first case max value is `0x7F*** = 2^(regsize-1)-1` (32767 for 16 bit), in the second case max value is `0xFF** = 2^regsize-1` (65535 for 16 bit)

(Note that there are `imul` and `mul` commands for multiplication, the first accounts for signs).

```
Hex byte example
80 imul 2 = FF:00
80  mul 2 = 01:00
```

Comment: I guess I understand, but then if i use the "neg" command, then the number will be set up as signed?

Comment: Register is just set of bits. It's your choice - interpret it as signed, unsigned, char etc. For example, byte register 11000000b=0xC0 might be considered as signed -20, unsigned 224, char À. Of course, application of `neg` command assumes that we work with signed number. But you can use result as unsigned.

Comment: @Bolololo321: BTW to `neg` the 32b `dx:ax` value is a bit more complicated than single instruction. `neg ax` `adc dx,-1` `not dx` would do that. But you shouldn't really need this, it's better to negate already one 16b side ahead of `mul`, to save yourself this hassle.